# When is the empty word part of A+?

Tags: formal-languages

My professor mentioned the below statement in class but without a proof. I am trying to prove it for myself as I don't understand 100% why this is always the case. 
Given is A, a subset of {0,1}$^*$.

ε $\in\ A^+$ <-> ε $\in\ A$, where ε is the empty word.
I thought of doing a proof by contradiction to show -> by assuming the empty word is not part of A$^+$.

Any help is much appreciated!